# Ruby: Write CSV line by line instead of whole file

Tags: ruby, csv

I am using the follow code to write to a CSV file. It writes the whole file at once. I would like to write the CSV file line by line by amending the file. How can I adjust my code?

```
  CSV.open("#{@app_path}/Data_#{@filename}", "w") do |csv|
    data_array.each do |r|
      csv << r
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's wrong with the implementation you have already? Is there a performance issue? Are you trying to write multiple data sets to the same file? Is there multiple threads accessing the same file? Are you concerned about the system failing when the file is only half-written? Are you facing some error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: My code takes hours creating the array, and sometimes it blows up and I need to rerun the whole script.  It would be great to start where I left off.

Comment: How large is `data_array`? Your could break the creation of `data_array` into chunks, initially do what you have for the first chunk, then subsquently make a copy of the file, append the chunk to that file (`CSV.open(<filename>, "a")`, rename or delete the original file and then rename the appended file to the original name.

Comment: What are you doing to "create the array" that takes hours? Maybe there is a better implementation to stream the data into the file without the need to create the `Array` in the first place.

Comment: To summarise the above, this feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. You're asking for assistance with a proposed solution, without really explaining the underlying problem. Maybe the array you're generating is infeasibly big, or the process is unnecessarily slow? Or maybe there's a nice way to generate the data "lazily", rather than all up-front, and write it to the file? I see `data_array` as being the root of your problem, not `CSV.open(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the problem is not the csv file, but the size of the array (and that after each fail you have to rebuild the array).

My attempt at solving that would be to process the array in chunks like below:

```rb
def process_array_by_chunks(array, starting_index = 0, chunk_size)
  return if array.empty?

  current_index = starting_index
  size = array.size
  stop = false

  while !stop do
    puts "doing index: #{current_index}"

    yield(array[current_index, chunk_size])

    stop = true if current_index >= size
    
    current_index = current_index + chunk_size
  end
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "failed at index: #{current_index}"
  puts "data left to process: "
  return array[current_index, size]
end

# call function with a block in which we write csv file
process_array_by_chunks(array, start, chunk_size) do | array|
  CSV.open(path, "w") do |csv|
    array.each do |r|
      csv << r
    end
  end
end
```

if that blows up for some reason the function will return an array with all the items that were not yet processed.